# Fast algorithm to detect main colors in an image?

Tags: python, algorithm, colors, python-imaging-library

Does anyone know a fast algorithm to detect main colors in an image?

I'm currently using k-means to find the colors together with Python's PIL but it's very slow. One 200x200 image takes 10 seconds to process. I've several hundred thousand images.

Comment: Random sampling might be an option if you really really need speed

Comment: I think k-means is pretty good choice because you know number of cluster beforehand. Maybe you need to optimize your implementation to achieve better performance or rewrite it in C or C++.

Comment: A very fast and Open Source C++ implementation of division based clustering can be found at my blog post here: http://www.modejong.com/blog/post17_divquant_clustering

Answer (score 10):

One fast method would be to simply divide up the color space into bins and then construct a histogram.  It's fast because you only need a small number of decisions per pixel, and you only need one pass over the image (and one pass over the histogram to find the maxima).

**Update:** here's a rough diagram to help explain what I mean.

On the x-axis is the color divided into discrete bins.  The y-axis shows the value of each bin, which is the number of pixels matching the color range of that bin.  There are two main colors in this image, shown by the two peaks.

[image: Color Histogram]

Comment: The easiest way is to take the top five bins in the histogram!  You might find fat peaks that sit across several bins - in this case you will want to find _local maxima_ instead of absolute maxima (ie. if you imagine the histogram with "hills" where the most frequent colours are, find the tops of the hills, rather than the top five points which are probably all on the one biggest hill).  You may find it helpful to smooth the histogram first.

Comment: Thanks @BrianL for the diagram. It's very clear now. Only problem is I don't know what Hue is. I'll try to find more information about Hue. Can I find Hue easily from RGB?

Comment: @bodacydo [`colorsys.rgb_to_hsv`](http://docs.python.org/library/colorsys.html) does this - the `h` is hue

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of tinkering, [this code](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/using-python-and-k-means-to-find-the-dominant-colors-in-images/) (which I suspect you might have already seen!) can be sped up to just under a second

If you increase the `kmeans(min_diff=...)` value to about 10, it produces very similar results, but runs in 900ms (compared to about 5000-6000ms with `min_diff=1`)

Further decreasing the size of the thumbnails to 100x100 doesn't seem to impact the results much either, and takes the runtime to about 250ms

Here's a slightly tweaked version of the code, which just parameterises the `min_diff` value, and includes some terrible code to generate an HTML file with the results/timing

```
from collections import namedtuple
from math import sqrt
import random
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image

Point = namedtuple('Point', ('coords', 'n', 'ct'))
Cluster = namedtuple('Cluster', ('points', 'center', 'n'))

def get_points(img):
    points = []
    w, h = img.size
    for count, color in img.getcolors(w * h):
        points.append(Point(color, 3, count))
    return points

rtoh = lambda rgb: '#%s' % ''.join(('%02x' % p for p in rgb))

def colorz(filename, n=3, mindiff=1):
    img = Image.open(filename)
    img.thumbnail((200, 200))
    w, h = img.size

    points = get_points(img)
    clusters = kmeans(points, n, mindiff)
    rgbs = [map(int, c.center.coords) for c in clusters]
    return map(rtoh, rgbs)

def euclidean(p1, p2):
    return sqrt(sum([
        (p1.coords[i] - p2.coords[i]) ** 2 for i in range(p1.n)
    ]))

def calculate_center(points, n):
    vals = [0.0 for i in range(n)]
    plen = 0
    for p in points:
        plen += p.ct
        for i in range(n):
            vals[i] += (p.coords[i] * p.ct)
    return Point([(v / plen) for v in vals], n, 1)

def kmeans(points, k, min_diff):
    clusters = [Cluster([p], p, p.n) for p in random.sample(points, k)]

    while 1:
        plists = [[] for i in range(k)]

        for p in points:
            smallest_distance = float('Inf')
            for i in range(k):
                distance = euclidean(p, clusters[i].center)
                if distance < smallest_distance:
                    smallest_distance = distance
                    idx = i
            plists[idx].append(p)

        diff = 0
        for i in range(k):
            old = clusters[i]
            center = calculate_center(plists[i], old.n)
            new = Cluster(plists[i], center, old.n)
            clusters[i] = new
            diff = max(diff, euclidean(old.center, new.center))

        if diff < min_diff:
            break

    return clusters

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    import time
    for x in range(1, 11):
        sys.stderr.write("mindiff %s\n" % (x))
        start = time.time()
        fname = "akira_940x700.png"
        col = colorz(fname, 3, x)
        print "<h1>%s</h1>" % x
        print "<img src='%s'>" % (fname)
        print "<br>"
        for a in col:
            print "<div style='background-color: %s; width:20px; height:20px'>&nbsp;</div>" % (a)
        print "<br>Took %.02fms<br> % ((time.time()-start)*1000)
```

Answer (score 0):

K-means is a good choice for this task because you know number of main colors beforehand. You need to optimize K-means. I think you can reduce your image size, just scale it down to 100x100 pixels or so. Find the size on witch your algorithm works with acceptable speed. Another option is to use dimensionality reduction before k-means clustering.

And try to find fast k-means implementation. Writing such things in python is a misuse of python. It's not supposed to be used like this.

Comment: Thanks @Lazin. I'll try to convert the image to 100x100, that should cut the runtime by 4 I think. Maybe 50x50 would also even work.